# How to get copy-paste value before that event change text field value in javascript

Tags: javascript

**I have questions regarding java scripts.**

Following is steps to reproduce it :

1. Text field having value 200.
2. Copy value from notepad (For ex : 500)
3. Select text field cursor at position second (i.e 2|00)
4. Paste copied values (500) on that cursor position.
5. it display values 250000 (It merge like[- is for just separator] 2-500-00).

But I want 500 only on that text field.

Can anybody suggest me how can I do it in JavaScript.

following is code snapes :

```
JSP code : onkeyup="javascript:formatCells(this.value)"
JS code : 

function formatCells(xls){
            var arrGroup = xls.split("\t");
                    alert(arrGroup);    
  }
```

Comment: please show some code, so that we can see you have applied some effort.  It will also show what you have in mind as well.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this. You're assuming that every time the user pastes something in the input field, that their intention is to replace the entire field with the new value. Maybe they don't want that. Maybe they want to paste in addition to what they have there already. In general i would avoid messing around with internal input field formatting. If you need to separate concepts (area code) phone-number, then provide separate inputs for each of those, rather than modifying what the user is typing.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with mastaBlasta that it is better not to modify expected behavvior of well known GUI-Elements. But to your Question, following example:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('paste',
  function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var clipboard = event.clipboardData,
    text = clipboard.getData('Text');
    console.log(text);
    event.target.value = 2 * text;
  }, false);
```

I have tested in in Firefox and Chrome.
The key is event.preventDefault() on the 'paste'-Event.

Comment: Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AW2Cm/) testet with Chrome 33, Firefox 28 and Opera 12.16